# SQL Insert command error

Tags: mysql

Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO film (film_id, title, description, release_year, language_id, original_language_id,
rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, last_update)
VALUES ('1001','1 st Grade FBI Agent','An undercover FBI agent must pretend to be
a 1st grade teacher to catch the bad guy', '2014','2','null', '5', '4.99', '123', '2014', 
'20.99', 'PG-13', 'Tailers');
```

Here is the error I get when I run it. This is a preset database I'm using for an assignment for a class, and I was told to insert a new row into the film table.

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sakila`.`film`, CONSTRAINT `fk_film_language_original` FOREIGN KEY (`original_language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`language_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Instead of `'null'`, you probably meant `null` (no single quotes)

Comment: The problem is obvious here, You put `NULL` as `original_language_id`, which violate foreign key constraint.  Or if you allow null on the column, you probably should write it as `NULL` instead of `'null'`

Comment: You are trying to insert a record a record which references a parent record in the `languages` table which does not exist or never did exist.  This is a data problem most likely, rather than a problem with the design.

Comment: Excellent answers guys, little tip - you'll get much better reputation points if you post these as answers, not comments.

Comment: can u send your total query from create table to insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL Statement is trying to INSERT  '`null'` value for the `original_language_id` field in the `film` table.

It looks like this `original_language_id` is a FOREIGN KEY that references the `language_id` in the `language` table and is likely the PRIMARY KEY on that table.

Comment: Ah yup. Thanks a ton! Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The value for original_language_id must match the value of language_id for one row in the language table. This requirement is due to a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on the film table.

If this value is an integer it should not be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are giving  'null' as value for original_language_id. Check, whether you have null as  value in your language table. If you want to insert  value null .... write it  just null not 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "original_language_id" is a foreign key from the "language" table and the value which you are trying to insert i.e 'null' in this case is not in the parent table(language).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few problems in your statement. But to answer the question that was asked, look at the "language" table. The value you put in original_language_id must be one of the values in the language.language_id column (or null, see below).

As for the other stuff, several users have already commented on the null value. null is a keyword and should not be in quotes.

ALso, your last 4 values seem to be in a different order than the field list.